# append or load page into body without removing inside content

Tags: jquery

```
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="content_1"></div>

<div class="content_2></div>

</div>
</body>
```

extracontent.html

```
<div class="content_3">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

how to i append my html page to body container without removing content inside ?i tried to use load but it remove all my element inside.

my code

```
  // $('.container').load('extracontent.html',
  //                            function(){alert('Content Successfully Loaded.')}
  // );
```

i tried to use append also but it wont as well.

```
// $('.container').append('extracontent.html');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$.get('extracontent.html', function(html) {
    $('.container').append(html);
});
```